# Difference between texture alias and spritesheet

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

what's the difference between a texture alias and a spritesheet in iOS? Are they one and the same thing?

Comment: just see this may be help you :http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24160/how-do-2d-art-assets-eg-sprites-work